# Error when running ./configure on Ubiquity source

Tags: install-from-source, pkg-config

I have added a patch to the Ubiquity source and am attempting to build and install the package to test it, however I get the following error when I execute `./configure`,

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config checking pkg-config is at least version
0.9.0... yes checking for PANEL... yes checking for CHEESE... no configure: error: Package 
requirements (glib-2.0
        gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10.0
        gobject-2.0
        pygobject-2.0
        cheese-gtk) were not met:

No package 'cheese-gtk' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a 
non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CHEESE_CFLAGS and CHEESE_LIBS to avoid 
the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

This is a truncated version - there's far more that came before this, but this is where the error occurred.

I have no idea where to start with this. I tried checking `man pkg-config`, but that didn't really help, except I now have a vague understanding of what pkg-config is supposed to do. None of the packages listed as being missing can be found by `apt-get`. I got `cheese` (different from `cheese-gtk` apparently) installed, but that hasn't helped. I would really appreciate some help troubleshooting this.

Comment: Try installing libcheese-gtk-dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `libcheese-gtk-dev`, and it'll work. Also, when building from source, it's a good idea to run `apt-get build-dep <package-name>` before building from source a package that is also available in the repositories (including any third-party repositories you have activated). This will pull in all the packages upon which the building of the package is dependent. Thanks to Jorge Castro's comment and [andrewsomething's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22480/error-when-running-configure-on-ubiquity-source/22501#22501) for this.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found out, you needed the `libcheese-gtk-dev` package. In the future, you can save yourself the headache of matching pkg-config checks with Ubuntu packages by using `sudo apt-get build-dep ubiquity` This will install all of the build dependencies for the package.